# Meaning of accessMask parameter in CommonAce Constructor (System.Security.AccessControl)

Tags: c#, security

What is the meaning of the accessMask parameter in [System.Security.AccessControl.CommonAce's Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonace.commonace%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Unfortunatelly the description "The access mask for the ACE." is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the SDK docs:

*A 32-bit value whose bits correspond to access rights for the object. Bits can be set either on or off, but the setting's meaning depends on the ACE type. For example, if the bit that corresponds to the right to read permissions is turned on, and the ACE type is Deny, then the ACE denies the right to read the object's permissions. If the same bit is set on but the ACE type is Allow, then the ACE grants the right to read the object's permissions.*

From the WinNT.h SDK header file:

```
//       3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
//       1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
//      +---------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
//      |G|G|G|G|Res'd|A| StandardRights|         SpecificRights        |
//      |R|W|E|A|     |S|               |                               |
//      +-+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
//
//      typedef struct _ACCESS_MASK {
//          WORD   SpecificRights;
//          BYTE  StandardRights;
//          BYTE  AccessSystemAcl : 1;
//          BYTE  Reserved : 3;
//          BYTE  GenericAll : 1;
//          BYTE  GenericExecute : 1;
//          BYTE  GenericWrite : 1;
//          BYTE  GenericRead : 1;
//      } ACCESS_MASK;
//      typedef ACCESS_MASK *PACCESS_MASK;
//
//  but to make life simple for programmer's we'll allow them to specify
//  a desired access mask by simply OR'ing together mulitple single rights
//  and treat an access mask as a DWORD.  For example
//
//      DesiredAccess = DELETE | READ_CONTROL
```